# MVC return View(model) Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is really unclear to me.
The code looks like this

```
 public ActionResult ViewDevice(string id)
 {
    FooObject model = new FooObject();

    if (id == null)
       return View(model);

    model = SomeMethodThatReturnsFooObject(id);

    return View(model);
 }
```

On my view, I check if Model is null, so I'm assuming this would work.

When ID is not null, I get the model variable filled by the FooObject.Fill and it displays well on the View.

When ID is null ...the controller gets this error at runtime:
"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".

Any reason why???

Comment: because you have a binding to some method on foobject that is null...

Comment: Meaning? In my view, when I create the new FooObject...model is NOT null any longer. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show the real model, and the view. If not, is impossible to determine the problem.

Comment: Model is n't null, model.Bar might be ...

Comment: Right, but on the actual view, i check for @if (Model != null) ..so there is access to properties on the view. Are you saying that at the controller level, the compiler checks for properties values before binding the variable to the return View() ?

Comment: Can you add your view code in your question?maybe in view you use from your Model.Id!!!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to return empty model object just do like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewDevice(string id)
 {

    if (id == null)
       return View();


    FooObject model = SomeMethodThatReturnsFooObject(id);

    return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
U can use this,

public ActionResult ViewDevice(string ?id)
 {
long _id = id ?? 0;

if(_id > 0)
{
FooObject model = SomeMethodThatReturnsFooObject(id);

return View(model);
}
return view();
}
```